# How do I assign value to outside variable from chrome API function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am facing problem when I am assigning value of a variavle from outside of a chrome api like the example below.

**Code:**

```
var btnStatus;

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({jsBlocker: "check"}, function(response) {
 btnStatus = response.data;
});

alert(btnStatus );
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendMessage` is asynchronous, which means that it will execute a passed callback only when it's ready, so it will take some time for a statement `btnStatus = response.data;` to happen. Again, because it is asynchronous the code below won't wait for `sendMessage` and will continue to run, as a result `alert` will show you the initial value of the `btnStatus` which is `undefined`. All your code which uses the data from response is dependent on this callback.
You could put an `alert` inside the callback to test a coming data and then do desired stuff with it:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({jsBlocker: "check"}, function(response) {
 btnStatus = response.data;
 alert(btnStatus);
});
```